# Replace particular value in all of the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

Got myself into one tricky(i feel so) problem when working with Pandas Dataframe(DF).

I have more than 10-15 DF columns with string of list of dict values in it. For example like this:

```
"[{u'firstLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000', u'clientId': u'abcd12345wtregse', u'lastLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000'}]"
```

I was trying to do this:

```
df = df.replace({"'":'""', 'u"':'"'})
```

What I was expecting with the above line of code was, it will replace all the single quote present in the DF and also it will replace **u"** with **"** but it seems to be not working with this line.

Expected output:

```
"[{""firstLogin"": ""2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000"", ""clientId"": ""abcd12345wtregse"", ""lastLogin"": ""2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000""}]"
```

How to replace/update all the single quote and string-like this **u"** from the string of list of dict in the whole of Pandas dataframe?

Sample Input:

```
column 1                                                                                                                        | column 2                                                                                                                           | column 3 
"[{u'firstLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000', u'clientId': u'abcd12345wtregse', u'lastLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000'}]" | "[{u'accepted': True, u'type': u'privacy_policy', u'id': 5872014}, {u'accepted': True, u'type': u'terms_of_use', u'id': 5872015}]" | "{u'type': u'password', u'value': u'2asdgdfjnasdgadfgd'}
```

I'm new to the Pandas, Could someone please help me to solve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem. First see DF which I defined as follows:

```
df1=pandas.DataFrame([{"col":"[{u'firstLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000', u'clientId': u'abcd12345wtregse', u'lastLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000'}]", "col2":"[{u'firstLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000', u'clientId': u'abcd12345wtregse', u'lastLogin': u'2018-08-30 08:19:29 +0000'}]"}])
```

This is the solution for this DF:

```
for col in  range(len(df1.columns)):
    col_name = df1.iloc[:,col].name
    temp=[]
    for rw in range(len(df1.index)):
        row_data = df1.iloc[rw,col].replace("'", '"')
        row_data = row_data.replace('u"', '"')        
        print(row_data)
        temp.append(row_data)
    df1[col_name]=temp
```

I also tried to replace by DF.replace() method that didn't work!
hope you got what you want?

Another method to do replace all the columns which is more effective as follows:

```
for col in  range(len(df1.columns)):
    col_name = df1.iloc[:,col].name
    df1[col_name] = df1[col_name].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", '"').replace('u"', '"') if type(x) == str else x)
```

this will totally solve this problem.

Comment: @Venkatesh_CTA I have added new solution for your problem, please check it